# hdf5 install on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, caffe, hdf5

I installed libhdf5 on Ubuntu via apt-get but there are no directories.

> sudo find -type d -name '*hdf5*'
>
> ./share/doc/hdf5-tools
>
> ./share/doc/libhdf5-mpich2-dev
>
> ./share/doc/libjhdf5-java
>
> ./share/doc/hdf5-helpers
>
> ./share/doc/libjhdf5-jni
>
> ./share/doc/libhdf5-mpich2-7
>
> ./local/MATLAB/R2016b/toolbox/matlab/imagesci/@hdf5
>
> ./local/MATLAB/R2016b/toolbox/matlab/imagesci/@hdf5/@hdf5type

I have some issue with hdf5 during compiling CAFFE. It's suggested to add path to hdf5 directory manually to Makefile.config but I can't find directory at all.

Hope someone can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Rerun the find from `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files were located in `/usr/include`. To make caffe compiled I manually created `/hdf5/serial` and put header files (`hdf5.h  hdf5_hl.h`) there.

Answer (score 0):

In my Linux Mint (similar to Ubuntu, at least apt-get...) I can find the headers under `/usr/include/hdf5` and the libraries under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.
If the installation was done correctly, I believe you should find the HDF5 stuff in similar places in your Ubuntu installation.
To locate the files you could try to execute in the terminal

```
locate hdf5
```

To be noticed that your command

```
sudo find -type d -name 'hdf5'
```

doesn't find the headers and libraries on my machine too.